# Remove duplicate attribute from HTMLString through regex

Tags: regex

I am having a HtmlString where the some tag is having multiple "href" attribute. I have to remove one of them. If href attribute is more then 1 then have to remove blank href attribute through regex.

```
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.It has
  <a title="Test PDF for RTF" href="" title="Test PDF for RTF" href="Test%20PDF%20for%20rtf.pdf">
     Test PDF
  </a>
  roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making
  <a title="Learn More" href="test.html" title="Learn More" >
    Learn More
  </a>
  it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock,
  <a title="Test Page" href="" >
    Test Page
  </a>
  Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,
  <a title="Test PDF for RTF" href="" title="Test PDF for RTF" href="Test%20PDF%20for%20rtf.pdf">
    Test PDF
  </a>
  looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur
</p>
```

Comment: Please provide an example and your efforts.

Comment: like this: <a href="http://" id="someAnchor" name="someAnchor" href="/">Link </a>

and remove 2nd href?

Comment: I have updated question with example

Comment: How did you end up in this situation? Are you generating the HTML yourself, did you inherit this error from somewhere outside of your control?

Comment: And is it sufficient to just remove all occurrences of `href=""`? Or is it important to keep tags like `<a title="Test Page" href="" >` intact? Can you ever have an `<a>` tag with two (or more) **non-empty** `href`s - in which case, which one do you choose to keep?

Comment: I have to keep one href, doesn't matter if it is empty,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want: match first `herf` in a line or text when it has two `href` and as with your comment: *I have to keep one href, doesn't matter if it is empty*. So you want to remove **duplicate** `href` and if so, you can apply:

```
(?=href.+?href)[^"]+""
```

this part: `(?=href.+?href)` is a lookahead assertion and match a zero-length just before the first `href` if it found twice, and this part: `[^"]+""` matches that empty `href=""`

## [`(?=href.+?href)[^"]+""`](https://regex101.com/r/kLGs5k/1)

A fest test of your input in a file:

```
perl -lne 'print $& while/(?=href.+?href)[^"]+""/g' file
```

It outputs:

```
href=""
href=""
```

and for removing:

```
perl -lpe 's/(?=href.+?href)[^"]+""/==>Removed<==/g' file
```

And it outputs:

```
  <p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.It has
  <a title="Test PDF for RTF" ==>Removed<== title="Test PDF for RTF" href="Test%20PDF%20for%20rtf.pdf">
     Test PDF
  </a>
  roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making
  <a title="Learn More" href="test.html" title="Learn More" >
    Learn More
  </a>
  it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock,
  <a title="Test Page" href="" >
    Test Page
  </a>
  Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,
  <a title="Test PDF for RTF" ==>Removed<== title="Test PDF for RTF" href="Test%20PDF%20for%20rtf.pdf">
    Test PDF
  </a>
  looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur
</p>
```

Also you can apply this pattern to [java](/questions/tagged/java) and just set the substitution to `""` empty

Answer (score 0):

A [possible solution](https://regex101.com/r/xxXKWU/4/) (removes duplicates and href=blank):

```
 (\w+=".*?")(?=[^>]+\1)|href="" //replace with nothing
```

Assumes that a `>` not occurring yet means that we're in the same tag, which is perhaps naive but maybe safe enough for your purposes.

Comment: It remove the href attribute from the <a> where only it only having 1 attribute. we have to remove href attribute where it exist more then 1

Comment: How is this any different from just replacing `href=""` with empty string? This seems to be matching every occurrence of `href=""`

Comment: actually some of link is having href attribute one time some are having 2 time, so I have to remove only those empty href where its occur 2 times then remove empty one.

Comment: Can we hardcore the "href" attribute and count if it is 2 then remove empty one? Thanks for your valuable help

Answer (score 0):

If it does not matter to leave  without a href when there is only one empty href:
`/\s?href=\"\/?\"/` would match all the occurrences of empty hrefs

Yo have not specified in which language you will use the regular expression so it might require a little tweaking.

Comment: I am using in java

Comment: its remove only first href empty attribute